# What am I doing wrong turning Pandas DF to dict?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a csv that looks like

```
AccountExternalID    Customer
1                    RogerInc
2                    FredLLC
```

I am turning that into a Pandas DF, and I want to turn that into a dict that looks like

{'RogerInc': 1, 'FredLLC': 2}

This is what I tried;

```
def build_custid_dict(csv_path: str=None) -> dict[str]:
    csv_path = r'\\path\CustomerIDs.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
    # Strip whitespace
    df[df.columns] = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
    df_dict = df.to_dict('list')
    return df_dict
```

Comment: Have you checked this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary or this documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Comment: It's out-dated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'AccountExternalID': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'Customer': {0: 'RogerInc', 1: 'FredLLC'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

output(`df`):

```
    AccountExternalID   Customer
0   1                   RogerInc
1   2                   FredLLC
```

**Code**

use following code in your func:

```
dict(df.iloc[:, [1, 0]].values)
```

result:

```
{'RogerInc': 1, 'FredLLC': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `to_dict` method will map the column headers to the column data. You don't want that for what you're trying to do.

Instead, you can do something like this:

```
ids = df['AccountExternalID'].values
customers = df['Customer'].values
df_dict = {customer:id for customer, id in zip(customers, ids)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one you can select one column of the dataframe as the key and another one as the value of dict.

```
def build_custid_dict(csv_path: str=None) -> dict[str]:
    csv_path = r'\\path\CustomerIDs.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
    # Strip whitespace
    df['AccountExternalID'].str.strip()
    df['Customer'].str.strip()
    df = df.set_index('AccountExternalID') 
    df_dict = df.to_dict('Customer')
    dict((v, k) for k, v in df_dict.items()) #reversing the keys and values
    return df_dict
```

Also refer to this [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941224/dataframe-to-dict-such-that-one-column-is-the-key-and-the-other-is-the-value)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `to_dict` method on a series, e.g.

```
df.set_index('Customer').AccountExternalID.to_dict()
```