# How to make dictionary from two pyspark columns keys and values

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark

I'd like to make a dictionary from two columns filtered from DataFrame. Content of the first column should be dictionary's key and from the second should be values of given key.

Example:

| keys | vals |
| --- | --- |
| 203 | 4 |
| 203 | 3 |
| 203 | 6 |
| 412 | 33 |
| 412 | 123 |

Such a dataframe I want transform to:

```py
final_dict = {
   "203": [4, 3, 6],
   "412": [33, 123]
}
```

Is there any fast method to avoid loops? Are they necessary here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dataframe to dict such that one column is the key and the other is the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941224/dataframe-to-dict-such-that-one-column-is-the-key-and-the-other-is-the-value)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: No, this answer was for pandas dataframe, not pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the function `collect_list` to get all the values from a group (use `collect_set` if you want distinct values instead):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

lst = df.groupby('keys').agg(F.collect_list('vals').alias('vals')).collect()

print({str(i[0]): i[1] for i in lst})
# {'412': [33, 123], '203': [4, 6, 3]}
```

Note that the `.collect()` command could take time if you have a large dataframe.

Comment: Exactly, what I wanted. Thanks!